# Assignment Branch Condition size for update_status is too high. [<1, 18, 8> 19.72/17]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can i fix this, when i try to condition if user.completed? == false or add when "completed" , i will has error

```
    def update_status
        status_cont = params[:status_cont]
        if user.completed? == false
          case status_cont
          when "waiting_email_confirm"
            user.waiting_email_confirm!
          when "email_confirmed"
            user.email_confirmed!
          when "ready_to_ship"
            user.ready_to_ship!
          when "shipped"
            user.shipped!
          when "canceled"
            user.canceled!
          when "completed"
            user.completed!
          end
        end
     end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a pattern in your `case` that you can use to simplify the logic. Something like this:

```
STATUS_CONTS = %w[canceled completed email_confirmed ready_to_ship shipped waiting_email_confirm]
private_constant :STATUS_CONTS

def update_status
  return if !user.completed?
  status_cont = params[:status_cont]
  raise "Unknown status_cont #{status_cont}" if !status_cont.in?(STATUS_CONTS)
  user.send("#{status_cont}!")
end
```

You'll probably want to handle unknown `status_cont` values differently but I don't know how the surrounding flow works.